# Molecular orbital basis mapping to computational basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-computer, second-quantization, molecules

I have some issues understanding the process of mapping a molecular orbital basis onto some basis in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. As described in many papers (for example [Simulation of Many-Body Fermi Systems on a Universal Quantum Computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9703054)), a molecular basis set with cardinality N, say $(\chi_1, \cdots, \chi_N)$ can be mapped onto (for example) the computational basis by denoting $|{b_1 b_2 \cdots b_N}\rangle$, where $b_i = 1$ iff the molecular orbital $\chi_i$ is occupied.

Now it makes total sense to me **mathematically** that a basis set of N molecular orbitals will lead to a computational basis with cardinality N. However I do not understand the physical meaning of this:
If we consider for example the molecule BeH2 with all of its 6 electrons in the ground state: It seems to me that all of the orbitals have to be occupied, so any state apart from $|{111111}\rangle$ would not be physical?

Also most of the literature seemingly addresses a more general case, where there are M electrons with $N > M$, so that may mean my mistake is already with the construction of the molecular orbital basis?

Any help is highly appreciated!

**Edit:** Maybe I should add some additional context as to what my goal is: I want to map the molecular basis onto the computational basis to do **VQE** on a quantum computer (simulator).

I have since spoken to a friend of mine and we came to the understanding that the ket $|111111\rangle$ would correspond to the ground state of the molecule. However, I cannot assume that I initally start off in the ground state, so the my initial state needs more degrees of freedom in some sense.

I think **this would change my question** to: For the 6 electron state, what cardinality would my basis have to have to reasonably perform VQE on it?

Comment: I can't get what you are asking specially. But generally, the wavefunction $\psi$ of the molecule should be written as $\psi=\sum_{b_i=0}^{1}|b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_N\rangle$. I don't know what's the difference between $M$ and $N$. Aren't they both molecular orbitals?

Comment: You are right, I did an error in the notation. M is supposed to be the number of electrons, N is the number of orbitals, and by the literature, $N > M$ is possible. My question in some sense is, for a 6 electron system BeH2, what would $N$ be?

Comment: I also don't understand your question. There are a few things that might help. 1. In many cases in chemistry, the ground state is all chemists care about, since most molecules are insulator with energy gap way larger than kT. This means that the electrons will essentially always occupy the electronic ground state. 2. Electrons have spin, so one molecular orbital in spacial coordinate can host two electrons with different spins. 3. The cardinality of basis set can be as large as one wants. If you have one electron in free space, you can include an unbounded number of basis vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am beginning to understand, atleast for my purposes. Still I have some questions about the intuition of the procedure if I may:
1. The ground state is also what I am interested in, however it seems as though I am already starting off with the ground state if I use $|111111\rangle$? 
2. Mainly the literature I found says that the number at a certain position within the ket represents the number of electrons that occupy it, so it seems as though a single orbital does not yet account for spin. Is this wrong? 
I will then rewrite the question for future readers.

Comment: As Bohan Xu said, you can use more orbitals $N$ than the number of electrons $M$. For example, if we use $N=10$ orbitals and then the wavefunction $\psi$ can be written as $\psi=\sum_{b_i=0,\sum b_i=6}^{1}C_{\vec{b}_i}|b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{10}\rangle$. And the ground state is $|1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0\rangle$. The other basis like $|1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0\rangle$ are all excited state and $|1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0\rangle$ is just the first excited state. So you can use any $N\geq M$ as you like and the bigger $N$ you choose, the more accurate model you can have in hand. It depends on the precision you need.